# Boolean Do-While Loop Never Stops

Tags: java, boolean, do-while

This is the working product of what everyone told me to do. Thanks guys, i'll try to keep
my code cleaner from now on. This code is just practice and is eventually just going to be a lock-out system for my computer that runs on start-up. Who wants pesky preteens messing around on their computer? not this guy.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;  /
class AgeChecker
{   
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception  /*@Exception- thrown to allow reading
    {                                                                       of single characters*/
    char ans; //(Read from user input)
    String name;
    boolean loop = false; //To loop back after a section, add loop = true.
                          //To stop the program after a section, add loop = false.
    do
    {
    Scanner dd = new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  // Needed to read the 
    BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // character input

    System.out.println("What is your name? "); name = dd.nextLine();
        {   

        System.out.println("Are you 14 years of age or older? (y/n) "); ans = (char)in.read();


                                    //Using if, else-if and else to make sure
            if (ans == 'y')         //I have a good grasp of what i already know
            {   
                    System.out.println("Welcome, " + name + "! Are you 21 years of age or older? (y/n) ");
                    ans = (char)in1.read();

                    if (ans == 'n')
                    {
                    System.out.println("Welcome, " + name + "!");
                    loop = false;
                    }

                    else if (ans == 'y')
                    {
                    System.out.println("Welcome, " + name + "! Would you like a drink? ");
                    loop = false;
                    }
                }   
            else if (ans == 'n')
                {   
                System.out.println("We're sorry. Only those at the age of 14 or older may access this program. ");
                loop = false;
                }   
            else 
                {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input. ");
                        loop = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (loop == true); //Put here to line up with the 'do' at the top
}
```

Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: You are setting fee to true every time.

Comment: I suggest you wrap System.in once, for the life of your program.  If you don't do this you can have strange buffering issues and discarded data.

Comment: Why two `{` after `main` method? Why so many empty lines? Please format your code prior to posting it, so it's easier for everybody to read, and we don't have to scroll more than necessary.

Comment: Is this better? (editted code)

Answer (score 7):

Replace

```
while (fee = true);
```

with

```
while (fee == true);
```

or better :

```
while (fee);
```

`fee = true` is an assignement and returns the assigned value (`true`).

Replace also

```
else 
System.out.println("Invalid input. ");
fee = true;
```

with

```
else {
   System.out.println("Invalid input. ");
   fee = true;
}
```

(thanks Rohit).

Note that it would be easier (including for you) to fetch those errors if your code had less spaces and less blocks (why so many ?). Those [code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) might be useful.

Comment: Or -- better yet -- `while (fee);`.

Comment: was it really that simple? Im a complete noob at this, thanks for your help

Comment: Also, you need to put a pair of braces in the last else. Otherwise, your `fee` will always be set to `true`.

Comment: +1 @RohitJain I'll add it to my answer if you don't want to make one.

Comment: @dystroy.. Of course go on. That is why I added it as comment. It's better to have one complete answer, than having a combination of two. ;) and this might also be a state of confusion for OP as to which one to mark selected.. ;)

Comment: Im just putting spaces and blocks for now for ease of reading on my part. After i finish my code, i usually take out alot of spaces and blocks.

Comment: Keep in mind i just started java this week. I'm new to the language, so what's readable to you might just hurt my head to look at.

Comment: @DamionDeslaurier.. Coding standards are not just designed for experts. You can also follow it without any fear. Don't worry. You won't get Head-ache at least. I take the onus for it.

Comment: Where might i find these coding standards that i should be following?

Comment: Follow these links ["Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language"](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html) and if you are hungry for more then ["Java Coding Standards"](http://www.ontko.com/java/java_coding_standards.html)

Comment: @DamionDeslaurier I've put a link in my answer. But the best thing to do would probably be for you to make your code look like good code (for example the one of java standard packages, [String.java](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java/?v=source)).

Comment: Thank you, i have now taken out spaces, documented, and just generally made this code easier for others to read.